# Bluetooth doesn't detect devices

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to pair Sony MDR-ZX550BN headset with Lenovo G580 laptop with Ubuntu 16.04. Laptop can't detect nor headset nor other devices (headset paired with smartfon works fine).

Some sources say that editing /etc/bluetooth/main.conf helps. I have done that, but nothing happened.

Other source said that disabling UEFI will solve the problem. But it didn't.

Blueman also detects nothing.

Is there any rescue for me except returning to Windows?

Here is output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb

```
    04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [17aa:0611]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b2e1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the solution is:

```
wget https://github.com/gnebehay/gnebehay.com/raw/master/contents/blog/lenovo-flexpad-bluetooth-debian/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd
sudo cp BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM.hcd
```

Then turn off and turn on (not restart).

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1509803/comments/87